# Relational databases SQL: Parent/Child relationships

Tags: mysql, relational-database

I am trying to learn SQL. I have three different tables. All the tables have one common column. I am showing a very small portion of sample data.
I am trying to understand how to read from a parent table after a child table has been updated.

```
Table_1    (booking platform info)
booking_date  column2 column3 column4    cust_country_id  hotel_id booking_value
22-mar-2016      ..................           1001          1         $150
01-apr-2016      ..................           1002          2         $500
09-apr-2016      ..................           1001          2         $222
17-apr-2016      ..................           1002          4         $75
19-apr-2016      ..................           1003          1         $690
03-May-2016      .................,           1001          3         $301 

Table_2 (hotel information)
hotel_id    hotel_name      hotel_country
  1          Marriott         Germany
  2          Novotel          France
  3          Oberoi           India
  4          Osaka            Japan




Table_3  (customer information)
  country_id    country_name
   1001           India
   1002           France
   1003           Japan
```

My question is if a new hotel Hyatt from France is added to Table_2 (hotel information), how can I find out the first date at which a French customer booked that hotel?

I am getting a bit confused on how to approach this; as it has to take values from all 3 tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case you should write mysql query to find the oldest booking_date for customer from France and hotel with name Hyatt

```
select booking_date from Table_1 
join Table_2 on Table_2.hotel_id = Table_1.hotel_id
join Table_3 on Table_3.country_id = Table_1.cust_country_id
where Table_3.country_name = 'France' and Table_2.hotel_name = 'Hyatt' 
order by Table_1.booking_date asc
limit 1
```